# Book about space traders who run into alien traders

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

From what I can remember, a down and out family of space traders, in which one female member of the family is a psychic or a witch, run into an alien ship, also running out of options.  Possibly the alien ship was alive, could be mistaken about that part.

Comment: Maybe Julie E Cznerneda? Try the Vattas War series too, that may be something you would like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Angel Station*](http://www.walterjonwilliams.net/2011/12/angel-station/) by [Walter Jon Williams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Jon_Williams) (1989)

Ubu has four arms, a fantastically faithful memory and is 13 years old. His 11-year-old sister Maria is more conventionally constructed, yet so psychic she considers herself a witch. (Both mature with the artificial aid of "mones" to the time of their late teens.) Their father, Pasco, a small-time trader with an ancient spaceship, originally assembled them from spare genetic material and personality programs, but he commits suicide while in the throes of a depression, leaving his children to fend for themselves. Ubu compounds their problems by making an unwise business move, putting them deeply in debt--in danger of losing the ship and facing a life of virtual indenture. An attempt to capitalize on Maria's psychic abilities in a casino ends in disaster, leading to their arrest, escape and lives pursued on the edge of the law.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much Dai.  I have 3 other books by WJW on my bookshelf but didn't realize I was missing that one.  I must have lent it to someone and never got it back.